# Laravel Import Large Json file to mySql

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to import around 35MB file of JSON data to MySQL DB,
But after certain data import, it throws a timeout error,

```
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

I have changed the php.ini execution time in my localhost xammp server, but still, it ends with the same errors,

Is there any way to increase the time or possible to chunk data in small sizes for import?

Comment: The same error with 60 seconds? Then you didn't change php.ini

Comment: @brombeer, I have increased it to 600 for the test, but still the same.

Comment: It is probably possible, but depends on your specific processing, so you need to supply more information.
On a hunch, I suspect that you might be converting the JSON into XML and the XML processor undergoes the "Schlemiel the Painter" effect.

Comment: @rjcode the time limit might be reset by Laravel. Try setting it explicitly in the import script using set_time_limit().

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question. Did you check `phpinfo()` if the value has been changed? Restarted the webserver?

Comment: I'm not convinced that a http request-response cycle is the ideal place for ingesting large amount of data into a database as it will take ages to finish. Such tasks are usually done by some kind of a background process, which posts regular updates on its progress

Comment: If you insist on doing this as part of http request response cycle, then you also need to check webserver's settings on script execution as it is often webservers that terminate long running processes.

Comment: You would probably be better off doing it with a [console command](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan) or [queued job](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues) instead of an HTTP request

Comment: @aynber, Thank you, i created job and run it via command and worked successfully,

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your webserver after any changes in php.ini
but you can use `set_time_limit(0)` after `<?php` in first line.

however 35MB is a large file to import by php and will lot burden of your memory.

you should import file directly to mysql

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-json-import-command.html